# What capacity will be lost by deorbiting Pirs

Tags: iss, pirs, nauka

[Nauka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_(ISS_module)) should, hopefully this year, replace the ISS' [Pirs module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirs_(ISS_module)).

While Nauka is already pretty old, I suspect it will bring a lot of interesting features to the space station.
However, Pirs might have some unique capability/features that might not be present in Nauka.

What would they be?

Answer (score 3):

The DC-1 module (PR name *Pirs*) provides a crew airlock and a docking port.

The MLM module (PR name *Nauka*) will not provide a crew airlock. It will provide a scientific airlock along with many other capabilities. It does have a docking port.

The MRM-2 module (PR name *Poisk*) will still provide the Russian side of the ISS with a crew airlock.

Source: http://www.khrunichev.ru/main.php?id=55